# create survey issue when using map in json file for POST method

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, react-native

```
async createSurvey(streamId, title, specialization, description, 
answers) {
let token = await getToken();
let url = '/api/survey';
let answer_text;
 answers.map((answer, index) => {
  answer_text = answer.answer;
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    question: {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      specialization: specialization,
      answers_attributes: {
        '0': {
          answer_text: answer_text
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return fetch(BASE_URL + url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token token=' + token
    },
    body
  }).then(res => {
   console.log('server response :', res);
    return res;
  }).catch(err => console.log('Fetch error :', err));
})
}
```

I am using this code, the map is for answers_attributes and so it creates survey same as the number of answers.length. so I want to avoid duplication. and I want to add map only for answers_attribute.please suggest me any solution for this.

edited:

when i pass the data :

title: 'Api testing',
          description: 'api description',
          specialization: 'Api specialization',
answers =[{answer_text: "answer1"}, {answer_text: "answer2 "}]

i am getting output:
 title: 'Api testing',
          description: 'api description',
          specialization: 'Api specialization',
answers =[{answer_text: "answer1"}]

title: 'Api testing',
          description: 'api description',
          specialization: 'Api specialization',
answers =[{answer_text: "answer2 "}]

but I want output:

title: 'Api testing',
          description: 'api description',
          specialization: 'Api specialization',
answers =[0: {answer_text: "answer1"}, 1: {answer_text: "answer2 "}]

So that means I am getting the whole data answers.length number of time. which is my issue.

Comment: do you still want to have a post request per each individual answer or you want to be able to post array with answers?

Comment: I want to post array with answers

Comment: what is the format of `answers_attributes`? is it an array of answers or an object with key corresponding to the index of an answer and value to the answer itself?

Comment: _Attributes format is like:                                                       
 answers_attributes =[{answer_text: "answer_as dzzxch"}, {answer_text: "answer_textx dvbxc "}]   I have edited my question please check this, you will get to know the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` directly to map to `answer_attributes`, no need to map every `answer` to an individual object to send to the server. Try this:

```
async createSurvey(streamId, title, specialization, description, answers) {
  let token = await getToken();
  let url = '/api/survey';

  const body = JSON.stringify({
    question: {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      specialization: specialization,
      answers_attributes: answers.map(answer => ({ answer_text: answer.answer }))
    }
  });

  return fetch(BASE_URL + url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token token=' + token
    },
    body
  }).then(res => {
    console.log('server response :', res);
    return res;
  }).catch(err => console.log('Fetch error :', err));
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)